# Mirrored object showing problems

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, mirror

I'm making a head model from another scene, and the body on a separate one. Both are different .blend files. Problem is when I copy (ctrl+c) the head model and paste it to the other scene (ctrl+v) the verts of the mirrored side of the object look clean compared to the original side.

Here is the scene of the head model. As you can see, both sides have retained consistency.
[image]

After I copy pasted the head model to the body scene, this is what I get.
[image]

The mirrored side looks inconsistent with the original side.

**I need both sides to look the same.**

Answer (score 2):

Problem is caused by lighting. I fixed mine by deleting the old lighting and creating new ones instead.